# Karma how get button element

Tags: javascript, html, angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I m trying to get the button element by query but i always get the error " Cannot read property 'triggerEventHandler' of null". I gave a id to the button but still no success. When i call a method of a component everything works though. Any ideas why ?

```
it('should return true if the therapist status not registered (1 or 2)', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const onClickMock  = spyOn(component, 'test');
    fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#toggleButton')).triggerEventHandler('click', null);
    expect(onClickMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

HTML

```
<button id="toggleButton" (click)="test()"></button>
```

Comment: can you try to pass an object in triggerEventHandler second argument  instead of null

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
const btn = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector("#toggleButton");
btn.click();
```

it should do the trick.

Comment: @TolgaTamer: Can you put `fixture.detectChanges()` once before this and tell me

Comment: @TolgaTamer : Something is not right. I have done this several time. Can you tell me the output of `fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('button'))` ? Does this have the button ? It should find that button if it is getting rendered in the HTML